# Why does complex object validation work like this, where as simple parameters do not?

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, data-annotations

In an ASP.NET Core application's controller, which has been decorated with the `[ApiController]` attribute, if we pass an empty JSON object for an Endpoint that expects the following object (From the request body, by default):

```
public class ComplexObject
{
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Prop1 must contain a positive number.")]
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }

    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Prop2 must contain a positive number.")]
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

validation fails as it should be (the properties are of type int, they are assigned the default value for that type, which is 0, which fails the validation check.

**But**, if we have an endpoint which does not accept a complex object (From the body), but rather 2 int variables from the URI, if the user just hits the endpoint without a query string (URI parameters), the validation seemingly passes, even though both properties are assigned the value of 0 when debugging.

What's different in this case that makes the validation pass, rather than not pass? Here is how I've decorated the attributes for the URI parameters:

```
public IActionResult SomeAction([Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Prop1 must contain a positive number.")] int prop1,
            [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Prop2 must contain a positive number.")] int prop2)
{
   ...
}
```

Obviously, if I also add the `[Required]` attribute, everything works as to be expected. But then why does SomeObject work without requiring a `[Required]` attribute? `[Range]` there basically kills two birds with one stone!

```
public IActionResult SomeAction([Required][Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Prop1 must contain a positive number.")] int prop1,
            [Required][Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Prop2 must contain a positive number.")] int prop2)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Action params are optional and they are only validated if they are present. As such, if you don't pass one of them, then the `Range` validation is not applied. When you post an entire object, you've satisfied that first condition: the param has a value. Therefore, validation will proceed on that object and subsequently all the properties it contains.

Then, since your properties are non-nullable ints, if you don't pass a value, then they will default to zero. Zero is outside the acceptable range, and therefore validation fails. It's not actually applying a required validation here. You're simply taking advantage of the fact that the default value is not acceptable to next piece of validation.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow pass no object, to a endpoint requiring object? I've tried that, but it seems the object itself can never be null - only an empty one (Just the curly brackets.)